# pytest setup_class() after fixture initialization

Tags: python, python-2.7, pytest

I am experimenting with pytest and got stuck with some unobvious behavior for me. I have session-scope fixture and use it like this:

```
@pytest.mark.usefixtures("myfixt")
class TestWithMyFixt(object):
    @classmethod
    def setup_class(cls):
        ...
```

And when I run test I see that setup_class() comes before fixture `myfixt()` call. What is the purpose behind such a behaviour? For me, it should be run after fixture initialization because it uses fixture. How can I use `setup_class()` after session fixture initialization?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6):

I found this question while looking for similar issue, and here is what I came up with.

1. You can create fixtures with different `scope`. Possible scopes are `session`, `module`, `class` and `function`.
2. Fixture can be defined as a method in the class.
3. Fixture can have `autouse=True` flag.

If we combine these, we will get this nice approach which doesn't use `setup_class` at all (in `py.test`, `setup_class` is considered an obsolete approach):

```
class TestWithMyFixt(object):
    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True, scope='class')
    def _prepare(self, myfixt):
        ...
```

With such implementation, `_prepare` will be started just once before first of tests within the class, and will be finalized after last test within the class.
At the time `_prepare` fixture is started, `myfixt` is already applied as a dependency of `_prepare`.

Comment: This approach did not work for me. I'm trying to instantiate classes in the `_prepare` method but I'm getting `AttributeError`

Comment: @RafaelC., you should check where does the error happen. Probably some issue with the classes you try to instantiate?
Also, note that `myfixt` fixture should exist somewhere outside your class.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code behind usefixtures it appears the fixtures are handled by FixtureManager [1] which works on a per instance level. By marking a class with usefixtures, it appears to denote to the test framework that each of the callables contained within the scope should use those fixtures, **but it does not apply the fixtures at that point**. Instead, it waits for the callable to be called at which point it checks all of the managers for any updates it should do (including the FixtureManager) and applies the pieces appropriately. I believe this means that for each test within your class, it will reapply the fixture so that each test starts from a common base point which would be better behavior than the contrary.

Thus, your setup_class is called because that's the earliest order of operations. It sounds like you should put your setup_class logic into your fixture which will cause it to be called at the time the fixture is implemented.

[1] - https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/master/_pytest/python.py#L1628

Comment: I can put some code in fixture initialization, but it is not right way. Suppose I have session fixture which starts database. And many classes depend on it and test it. But in one I perhaps want to create table in db once at tests startup and use it in each test. It is not convenient to create table every time in setup() or create it globally in fixture start. Maybe I should use other methods instead of session fixture?

Comment: @DuXeN0N I'd actually argue it is. The way I have my unit testing setup, I recreate my local in memory sqlite database (and populate it for whatever the test battery is) for every single test. If you don't do it this way you will (guaranteed) have pollution between tests because you'll forget about modified, deleted, or added data. So I agree that there are certain things you want to do once (in which case, store in a config file that you've already done them and just check in your fixture) otherwise do full setup for each test.

Comment: Database could be recreated, but what if this is, for example, Hadoop cluster? I can't prepare cluster with nodes each test. It will increase testing time significantly. But all in all, thank you!

Comment: @DuXeN0N if you're spinning up a cluster for your unit tests you're likely doing something wrong. There are ways to test hadoop functions without spinning up a cluster as that's super time consuming and not very unit-test-ee in my opinion (e.g. is it a failure in your code if distributed HDFS has a hiccup?)

Answer (score -1):

I  know is an old post but the answer is pretty simple, maybe it will be useful for others.

You have to call `super(...).setUpClass` method in current `setUpClass`.

`setUpClass` is called once before the test methods and perform all actions. when you call `super(...).setUpClass` it applies the fixtures.

Note 1: i made some small changes to the code to be prettier.

Note 2: this method should be called `setUpClass`, it is mandatory.

```
class TestWithMyFixt(APITestCase):
    fixture = ["myfixt"]
    
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        super(TestWithMyFixt, cls).setUpClass()
        ...
```

This is my opinion, but maybe the purpose of this behavior is let the developer to choose when he want to load the fixture.